# Xcode addSubview: (View Controller) - iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Hy,
so i have a question about adding a subview. I'm just created an iPad app which has a home screen i which i should add a subview at some point . But when i use :

```
NotesMainViewController *openNotes = [[NotesMainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NotesMainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:openNotes.view];
```

the main view imports that another view, but the controls on it like UITextField or anything else don't work. So, can please anybody tell me how can I add a view from ViewController to a another view (in that case homeViewController). I have been trying with the addsubview method but it doesn't work.

Comment: "don't work" isn't helpful. Are the controls not visible? Disabled? Do they not trigger their action? Do they not detect taps?

Comment: it seems that the problem is in the delegate method. When i set the delegate to the textfield on it's viewcontroller, it breaks. When i set the textfield delegate on the viewcontroller in which is added, it works fine but i can't get the value from it... What is the best method to delegate textfield. Because textField.delegate = self; doesnt' work